# Category Theory for Rings, Groups, Modules

Tags: category-theory

I just know a little about category theory so I just want to ask why do we need group homomorphisms, ring homomorphisms, and module homomorphisms as morphisms in a category of such objects? Why can't it be just ordinary functions?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want your "category of groups" to be about groups, then you need the functions to "somehow" reflect that they are groups. Otherwise, you are just dealing with them as sets, and then what's the point of thinking of them as groups?

Comment: Categories are essentially determined by their morphisms. This can be made precise via the Yoneda lemma

Answer (score 1):

First - wellcome to the realms of abstract nonsense - the objects and arrows (ie "morphisms") in your category are nothing but *labels*. In the sense of category theory, "morphisms" don't even need to be functions : they're just *names*.

It is true that in the categories you mention above the objects and arrows have very convenient names : say you have two groups/rings/whatever $A$ and $B$, and a group/ring/whatever - homomorphism $f : A \mapsto B$, then the object (resp. arrow) labelled $A$ (resp. $f$) will correspond to its name. Whence the common confusion between "morphism" (as in "arrow") and morphism (as in whatever-morphism).

But in general, a category is just whatever name space you might fancy. And now we come to the answer to the intended question :
If you want your category to carry any meaning, you have to chose arrows that somehow

1. preserve the defining properties of the objects in your category.
2. reflect all the possible meaningful interactions between objects in your category

And - in general - you want to take as few arrows as possible to soundly do so because it makes the $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$s sharper tools to observe your objects since they're less cumbersome.

All in all, remember that the $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$s are elegant weapons for a more civilized age. :-)